# Could someone explain the files generated when we compile android code in Xamarin (mono for android)?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin

When I compile my code in C# using Xamarin (mono for android), I see the following 5 files created in the `bin/` directory.

1. SolutionName.SolutionName.apk
2. SolutionName.SolutionName-Signed.apk
3. SolutionName.dll (Application extension)
4. SolutionName.dll.mdb (Microsoft Access Database)
5. SolutionName.pdb (Program Debug Database)

Could someone explain what these files mean and whether if it is possible to deploy my application manually (Without using Xamarin) using these files?

Comment: .apk is the file that can be run on the `Phone` :)

Comment: I have added the missing file extensions to your question. If you are truly a developer, *please* enable "show file extensions" in Windows explorer. It will make your life so much easier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. SolutionName.SolutionName.apk is the unsigned Android package
2. SolutionName.SolutionName-Signed.apk is the signed Android package
3. SolutionName.dll is just the dynamic library
4. SolutionName.dll.mdb is the Mono debugging symbols (not Microsoft Access Database)
5. SolutionName.pdb is the .NET debugging symbols

Comment: Using these set of files, is it possible to deploy into a device without using Xamarin tool?

Comment: Sure, you can use adb directly.